# Windows PowerShell: changing the command prompt

Tags: windows, powershell

Using Windows PowerShell, how do I change the command prompt?

For example, the default prompt says

```
PS C:\Documents and Settings\govendes\My Documents>
```

I want to customize that string.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Just put the function `prompt` in your PowerShell profile (`notepad $PROFILE`), e.g.:

```
function prompt {"PS: $(get-date)>"}
```

or colored:

```
function prompt
{
    Write-Host ("PS " + $(get-date) +">") -nonewline -foregroundcolor White
    return " "
}
```

Comment: `notepad $PROFILE` doesn't work in Windows 7 from an admin powershell prompt

Comment: Ahh, I see that you need to create the profile first: `new-item -itemtype file -path $profile -force`

Comment: Note: You can just paste the prompt function in powershell to change the prompt path instead of saving the function in your profile, but you will have to do this every time you launch powershell.

Comment: You also need to run Powershell as admin and do `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`.

Comment: `function prompt {"foo >"}` works for me as a one-liner.  But I'll have to look into the `$PROFILE`.  You can also put the `pwd` command in there...

Comment: @qed `Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` if you only want to change for the current user or can't run as admin.

Comment: Worked for me exactly as described, in Windows 10, PowerShell, as normal user, ie. 1. `new item ...`; 2. `notepad  $PROFILE`; 3. put `function prompt {...}` in the editor and save. The prompt was changed immediately on saving the file.

Comment: What is the advantage of return " " in the prompt Windows function?

Comment: @Timo From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_prompts?view=powershell-7.1): _"The Prompt function must return an object."_ and _"The default prompt appears only when the Prompt function generates an error or does not return an object."_ So w/o that `return` you will get an additional `PS>` added at the end of the prompt, because `Write-Host` does not return an object.

Answer (score 29):

Related to a comment to [Ocaso Protal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725888/windows-powershell-changing-the-command-prompt/5725988#5725988), the following is needed for Windows Server 2012 as well as Windows 7 (in a PowerShell window):

```
new-item -itemtype file -path $profile -force
notepad $PROFILE
```

I would suggest the following as a prompt if you run with multiple user names (e.g. yourself + a production login):

```
function Global:prompt {"PS [$Env:username]$PWD`n>"}
```

(Credit goes to David I. McIntosh for this one.)

Comment: You also need to run Powershell as admin and do `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`.

Answer (score 13):

At the prompt, I like a current timestamp and resolved drive letters for network drives. To make it more readable, I put it in two lines, and played a bit with colors.

With CMD, I ended up with

```
PROMPT=$E[33m$D$T$H$H$H$S$E[37m$M$_$E[1m$P$G
```

For PowerShell, I got the same result with:

```
function prompt {
    $dateTime = get-date -Format "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"
    $currentDirectory = $(Get-Location)
    $UncRoot = $currentDirectory.Drive.DisplayRoot

    write-host "$dateTime" -NoNewline -ForegroundColor White
    write-host " $UncRoot" -ForegroundColor Gray
    # Convert-Path needed for pure UNC-locations
    write-host "PS $(Convert-Path $currentDirectory)>" -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Yellow
    return " "
}
```

Which is a little more readable :-)

BTW:

- I prefer `powershell_ise.exe $PROFILE` instead of (dumb) [Notepad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29).
- If you like to debug your prompt() with breakpoints, you should rename the prompt-function to anything else (or try it in another file). Otherwise you might end up in a loop: When you stop debugging, prompt() is called again and you stop at the breakpoint, again. Quite irritating, at first...

Answer (score 10):

If you want to do it yourself, then [Ocaso Protal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5725988/3850697) is the way to go. But if you're lazy like me and just want something to do it for you, then I highly recommend [Luke Sampson's Pshazz package](https://github.com/lukesampson/pshazz).

Just to show you how lazy you can be, I'll provide a quick tutorial.

- Install Pshazz with [Scoop](http://scoop.sh/) (`scoop install pshazz`)
- Use a nice predefined theme (`pshazz use msys`)
- Drink (root) beer

Pshazz also allows you to create your own themes, which is as simple as configuring a JSON file. [Check out mine](https://github.com/fomentia/pshazz-themes/blob/master/fomentia.json) to see how easy it is!

Answer (score 10):

To just show the drive letter I use:

```
function prompt {(get-location).drive.name+"\...>"}
```

Then to revert to the path I use:

```
function prompt {"$pwd>"}
```

Answer (score 7):

This version of [Warren Stevens' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20960378/7122647) avoids the noisy "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem" in the path if you `Set-Location` to network shares.

```
function prompt {"PS [$Env:username@$Env:computername]$($PWD.ProviderPath)`n> "}
```

Answer (score 3):

## PowerShell Prompt

In case someone is looking for a more sophisticated answer, here's my PowerShell v7 prompt that I have developed over the course of a year. To put it into context, it's part of my personal PowerShell profile:

https://github.com/StefanGreve/profile

## Disclaimer

The easiest way to get a fancy PowerShell prompt up and running is to use established solutions created by the pwsh community, so if you just need something that works with few lines of code to write on your end, you might want to take a look at this project:

https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git

However, if you are like me and want to write your own custom prompt from scratch, then the code snippets below might be able to give you some ideas on how to approach this problem.

## Custom Prompt

I will break down the most important pieces here. To start things of, I added the necessary code to determine the current platform we are on (since some bits are OS-specific and I also use this function on Unix-based operating systems):

```
enum OS
{
    Unknown = 0
    Windows = 1
    Linux = 2
    MacOS = 3
}

# I map these booleans to an Enum so that I can switch over them
$global:OperatingSystem = if ([OperatingSystem]::IsWindows()) {
    [OS]::Windows
} elseif ([OperatingSystem]::IsLinux()) {
    [OS]::Linux
} elseif ([OperatingSystem]::IsMacOS()) {
    [OS]::MacOS
} else {
    [OS]::Unknown
}

# In the prompt function below this is used to toggle the leading char ('>' or '#') to indicate elevated privilages
if ([OperatingSystem]::IsWindows()) {
    $global:IsAdmin = ([Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)
}

if ([OperatingSystem]::IsLinux()) {
    $global:IsAdmin = $(id -u) -eq 0
}
```

```
# Required for Python if you want to set the venv indicator in the terminal yourself, else skip this part
$env:VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT = 1
```

```
# Returns the execution time of the last command you ran, or 0 on init
function Get-ExecutionTime {
    $History = Get-History
    $ExecTime = $History ? ($History[-1].EndExecutionTime - $History[-1].StartExecutionTime) : (New-TimeSpan)
    Write-Output $ExecTime
}
```

After the build up, we can continue to dive into the actual prompt function:

```
function prompt {
    $ExecTime = Get-ExecutionTime

    # Only show the current branch if we are inside a Git repository. Notice that the Git command writes to stderr if we are not inside a Git repository
    $Branch = if ($(git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree 2>&1) -eq $true) {
          # If you version of git doesn't support the --show-current flag yet, use this command instead:
          # git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
          # It's less readable so I opted for the more modern approach but you may want to use the command above if using the latest versions of programs isn't your thing
          [string]::Format(" {0}({1}){2}", $PSStyle.Foreground.Blue, $(git branch --show-current), $PSStyle.Foreground.White)
    }

    # You can delete this part if you don't use Python, it is used to indicate whether a virtual environment is active
    $Venv = if ($env:VIRTUAL_ENV) {
        [string]::Format(" {0}({1}){2}", $PSStyle.Foreground.Magenta, [Path]::GetFileName($env:VIRTUAL_ENV), $PSStyle.Foreground.White)
    }

    $Computer = switch ($global:OperatingSystem) {
        ([OS]::Windows) {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                UserName = $env:USERNAME
                HostName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
            }
        }
        ([OS]::Linux) {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                UserName = $env:USER
                HostName = hostname
            }
        }
        ([OS]::MacOS) {
            # I don't have a Mac so I cannot guarantee that this bit works, but in theory it should do the trick based on what I found online
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                UserName = id -un
                HostName = scutil --get ComputerName
            }
        }
    }

    return [System.Collections.ArrayList]@(
        "[",
        $PSStyle.Foreground.BrightCyan,
        $Computer.UserName,
        $PSStyle.Foreground.White,
        "@",
        $Computer.HostName,
        " ",
        $PSStyle.Foreground.Green,
        [DirectoryInfo]::new($ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation).BaseName,
        $PSStyle.Foreground.White,
        "]",
        " ",
        $PSStyle.Foreground.Yellow,
        "(",
        $ExecTime.Hours.ToString("D2"),
        ":",
        $ExecTime.Minutes.ToString("D2"),
        ":",
        $ExecTime.Seconds.ToString("D2"),
        ":",
        $ExecTime.Milliseconds.ToString("D3"),
        ")",
        $PSStyle.Foreground.White,
        $Branch,
        $Venv, # (you may want to remove this line, see remark above)
        "`n",
        [string]::new($global:IsAdmin ? "#" : ">", $NestedPromptLevel + 1),
        " "
    ) -join ""
}
```

Comment: Nice job! I like the array at the end. That makes it easier to follow and make changes.

Comment: Nice detail Stefan, thanks! When using, say the .Foreground property, do you have to use a named colour or can you use an RGB value in some fashion? To me (pseudo) obj.Background = "14;37;55" #Blue-Grey Slate, scans easier but I get issues between versions of powershell and have to just set it manually for long sessions *ugh*!

Comment: @RussClarke You can use RGB colors if your terminal supports true colors by using ANSI escape sequences, see also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62617584/10827244. In that case, you could write a custom Cmdlet or use an existing one such as https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Communary.ConsoleExtensions/1.0.69/Content/Functions%5CWrite-RGB.ps1, and write `Write-RGB $([System.Collections.Array]@(...))` instead of the `return` at the end of the `prompt` function.

TLDR: It's possible, but not with the `-ForegroundColor` or `-BackgroundColor` options because they expect these enums.

Comment: One word of advice, it's faster to use string concatenation instead `Write-Host`-ing each line, and since the prompt function is called fairly frequently that's one thing to consider. Replacing the `$PSStyle.Foreground.*` with an ANSI escape sequence would be better. For example, `Write-Host "$([char]0x1b)[38;2;100;100;100mTEST$([char]0x1b)[0m"` prints the string `TEST` with `RGB=100,100,100` (as foreground because of the `38;2` bit, else use `48;2` for background coloring), and then reset it again (`0m`). See also https://gist.github.com/fnky/458719343aabd01cfb17a3a4f7296797 for more details.

Answer (score 1):

**PROMPT in PowerShell**

A better way to track the path, while keeping the hostname and logging time/date in every line run:

```
function prompt {
    $dateTime = get-date -Format "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"
    $currentDirectory = $(Get-Location)
    $UncRoot = $currentDirectory.Drive.DisplayRoot
    write-host "$dateTime" -NoNewline -ForegroundColor YELLOW
    write-host " $UncRoot" -ForegroundColor White
    # Convert-Path needed for pure UNC-locations
    write-host "$ENV:COMPUTERNAME-PS:$(Convert-Path $currentDirectory)>" -NoNewline -ForegroundColor GREEN
    return " "
}
```

...and you get:

```
myservername-C:\Users\myusername\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\scripts>
```

Finally! :)