# Change PowerShell appearance - Command Line on line below directory

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line, appearance

I was wondering if it is possible to change the appearance of PowerShell, so you have the command line a line below your directory line:

```
C:\your\directory\path\will\go\here >
$ now-a-super-long-command-can-be-entered-here
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows powershell: changing the command prompt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725888/windows-powershell-changing-the-command-prompt)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to modify the `prompt` function.

The following would do what you want:

```
function prompt {
    Write-Host "$(Get-Location) > "
    return "$ "
}
```

Simply pasting it into an existing PowerShell window will enable it immediately. If you want to make it permanent, add it to your `profile.ps1`.

[This link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb613488.aspx) has information about modifying the profile.