# PowerShell/Command Prompt script with custom properties (visual looks)

Tags: powershell, cmd

You can customize your Command Prompt or PowerShell window to have your own custom text color, background color, buffer size, etc.

But when I run a .cmd .ps1 .bat file it always runs with the default scheme. Is there any way that I can run these files with my custom properties loaded?

Comment: How do you launch these scripts? I'm unable to reproduce on Windows 7

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen You just open up a text editor and type exactly what you would type normally in the shell, and then save it with one of those file extensions. Then simply double click the now runnable file.

Comment: Interesting. If I open up cmd, change the color scheme, exit and then either double-click, launch from "Run..." or call from within a new cmd.exe process, colors are as I set them in the previous session

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I'm talking about when you run a script, not when you just boot it up regularly. After you set these custom properties, try to run a script and it'll boot up using the default black/white scheme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit your powershell profile script to edit your prompt on script startup. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20960378/895739) for some insight on that.

As an example of how to do it, paste the following in an Administrative PowerShell session:

```
New-Item -ItemType File -Path $PROFILE -Force
Out-File -FilePath $PROFILE -Force -InputObject 'Function Global:Prompt { "PS: Hello $Env:USERDOMAIN\$Env:USERNAME $PWD>" }'
```

Where the first line creates the $PROFILE file for your PS sessions, and the second line sets the 'prompt' function to be used in every session. In this example, I set the prompt to include the current username/domain in the prompt before the current directory.

Note that you should likely edit the $PROFILE file in an editor instead, I only offer this as an example. [You can do all sorts of great stuff with your prompt and other session settings in that file](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847739.aspx), setting the [colour of messages](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692799.aspx), adjusting prompt to [location and contextual status at that path](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git/blob/master/profile.example.ps1), and other fascinating things. Be cautious not to do too much - simplicity is best.

Comment: So from very brief testing this seems to be the way to go, but just out of curiosity, since I've already set some custom properties, is there anywhere I can find them so that I can paste them easily into my $PROFILE? For example, I tried out the built in "darkgray" and it wasn't dark at all; if there's a way to use hexcodes or something that would be great.