# Showing time and/or date on powershell command prompt

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to have powershell show the time and/or date on the command prompt so that, for example, I can see when the last command was executed?

Something like this:

```
C:\git\MyProj [feature/delivery +0 ~6 -0 !] [14:32:02]>
```

This is not a duplicate because I would like to maintain poshgit integration while adding the time to the prompt. The related post replaces the entire prompt with a custom prompt. I am asking for an augmentation while leaving any other plugins intact.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows powershell: changing the command prompt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725888/windows-powershell-changing-the-command-prompt)

Comment: You have to make the change in the profiler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

poshgit provide [example instructions how to do this](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git#customizing-the-posh-git-prompt), though they are out of date with my version of of poshgit.

type `$GitPromptSettings` at the prompt to view the list of settings. My system lists the `DefaultPromptSuffix` as being set to `$('>' * ($nestedPromptLevel + 1))`

To change it, open your PowerShell profile file (type `$profile` at the prompt to get its location, or just `notepad $profile` to open it)

Below the `Import-Module` line for posh-git, add the following:

```
$GitPromptSettings.DefaultPromptSuffix = ' [$(Get-Date -f "HH:mm:ss")]$(">" * ($nestedPromptLevel + 1))'
```

or, if you wanted the time as a prefix:

```
$GitPromptSettings.DefaultPromptPrefix = '[$(Get-Date -f "HH:mm:ss")] '
```