# How to change PowerShell Cursor to a pipe

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell PROFILE file with some startup settings. I need to change the cursor so that when PowerShell is started, together with other settings, it also starts with pipe cursor. How can I change the PowerShell cursor into a pipe, | ?

Comment: Why?  You realise the pipe character is a _very_ special character in PowerShell and this seems like it will just be confusing.  In any case, did you mean you want to change the 'prompt' (i.e. the `PS C:\>`)?  If so, check out this previous question:  [Windows powershell: changing the command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725888/windows-powershell-changing-the-command-prompt)

Comment: @boxdog, I meant the blinking cursor. I find it more easier to move the pipe as a cursor and determine its position, i.e. before or after a character.