# Undo Conda Powershell prompt modification

Tags: powershell, conda

`Conda 4.6.14` over-writes my default PowerShell prompt from:

```
C:\whatevs\okay>
```

to:

```
(env) PS>
```

but I ideally want what it was previously:

```
(env) C:\whatevs\okay>
```

How can I undo this change to my PowerShell prompt? I like knowing what path and Conda environment I'm using whenever I execute a command! Is there a setting I can change?

I know it's possible to modify the [PowerShell prompt by editing `$profile`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5725888/1079075). However, I want to keep the `(env)`. Is there some quick way to get the current Conda environment so I can include it into a custom path?

## Details

The file being modified by `conda init` is `$HOME\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1` who's contents are:

```bsh
#region conda initialize
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
(& "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe" "shell.powershell" "hook") | Out-String | Invoke-Expression
#endregion
```

Comment: have you found the code that is changing your prompt?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I have and updated the question accordingly

Comment: ok - now you can capture that `Out-String` and see the code being run by `Invoke-Expression`. [*grin*]

Comment: Looks like my profile.ps is in OneDrive\Documents\WindowsPowershell. And I see what conda did! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [an issue with Conda `4.6.14`](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8598) and can be resolved by downgrading back to `4.6.12` or [upgrade to the (currently) experimental `4.7`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56432639/1079075).