# Update conda to development version

Tags: conda

I have Conda 4.6.14 installed, which has [some issues I would like to resolve](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55923854/1079075). According to [Conda's GitHub release page](https://github.com/conda/conda/releases), version 4.7.0 is available. However, when I run `conda update conda` Conda informs me the newest version is already installed.

Is there any ways to directly update to a specific Conda version? Can I point Conda to the release zip file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the latest conda releases, you should add the [Conda Canary channel](https://www.anaconda.com/what-conda-canary/) before executing `conda update conda`.