# Does powershell have something like "echo off" in command prompt mode?

Tags: powershell

In CMD command prompt, the `echo off` command disables the command prompt to be shown in the "Command Prompt Window".

i.e., it does not show the **folder path anymore** in the prompt, giving you a clean dark window.
I've put a gif below to make this very clear:

After the `echo off` command, the prompt doesn't show the path "C:\Users\TEMP>" anymore, until I type `echo on` again.

Does powershell have something like this? Sorry if this is silly. I tried to look for it, but didn't find a simple answer regarding the command prompt window (not a script execution).

[image]

Comment: There is not a direct quick fix though, but maybe [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725888/windows-powershell-changing-the-command-prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725888/windows-powershell-changing-the-command-prompt) can help you.

Comment: Ok. Then . . . there isn't that functionality, really . . .

Comment: What are you really trying t accomplish? If you never want to see the prompt on the interactive command line, then you can set that, using what you've been shown in the accepted answer, in you PowerShell profiles, and set the prompt string in the console title bar, which can be set to dynamically change as you move thru you directories. Thus eliminating the need to flip in and out like what you are doing.  Or at any time, you just type $pwd, to display your current working directory. Just say'in...

Comment: Yes, I will use the accepted answer. Even having a inicial "space" string, that is enough for me. I don't have the need to flip in and out like in the gif. It was just an example of the use of `echo` in the prompt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the backspace control character.

```bsh
function prompt { echo " `b" }
```

[image: no prompt message]

Comment: This answer is better. I will accept it as the correct.

Comment: @7cc How does PowerShell 7.0 react when you type in `{` or `for` with this prompt? PowerShell 5.1 will crash.

Comment: @Thomas It works fine with v7. For v5, I can reproduce the crash when set this prompt in the terminal, but no crash when set in profile.ps1 or `powershell -NoExit -Command "function prompt { echo " &#x60;b" }"`

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of `echo off` is not to hide the prompt in cmd, but to disable command echoing (especially used in batch scripts). As PS does not have command echoing, it does not have a way to disable it. But as you just want to change your prompt:

You can change your prompt, but not to an empty string. If you return an empty string, PS will use its default prompt:

```
function prompt {}
```

Result:

```
PS>echo hello
hello
PS>
```

You could return a space character:

```
function prompt {' '}
```

Result:

```
 echo hello
hello
```

But then each line is prefixed with a space. You could also use the interesting hack from [7cc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61503728/11942268) and insert a character with an appended backspace character. But be aware that at least PowerShell 5.1 will *currently* crash, when using a prompt that is shorter than two characters. It will crash as soon as you type in `{` or `for` for example. And it will be buggy, if the prompt does not end with a space character (a character of the prompt disappears, when typing `{` or `for` for example). So it is probably the best to go with something like `>` followed by a space character as the shortest prompt:

```
function prompt {'> '}
```

The current built-in prompt is defined like this btw:

```
function prompt {
    $(if (Test-Path variable:/PSDebugContext) { '[DBG]: ' }
      else { '' }) + 'PS ' + $(Get-Location) +
        $(if ($NestedPromptLevel -ge 1) { '>>' }) + '> '
}
```

[Read more about prompts in PS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_prompts?view=powershell-7)

Comment: Thank you! `function prompt {' '}` will be enough for me.

Comment: Hi @Thomas, thank you for the remarking about PS crash. I will be aware. When I need to use that commands (or even more complex commands) I'll turn back to some acceptable prompt message.

Answer (score -1):

I use the following:
@echo on:  Set-PSDebug -Trace 1 
@echo off: Set-PSDebug -Trace 0 

simple :)