# How to hide "PS C:\>" in powershell?

Tags: powershell, prompt

So you know how in powershell if you enter a command infront of it there will always be "PS (directory)>".
I know its possible in cmd with a simple command but how do you do this in powershell?

so:

- Hide the text(PS C:>) thats infront of commands
- If possible through a command

If any of you know the fix please let me know.
If i find it first i will self anwser.

(I later found this dup):[Windows PowerShell: changing the command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725888/windows-powershell-changing-the-command-prompt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like Calculuswhiz mentioned, the following should work:

```
Function Prompt {" "}
```

Simply change it by adding anything else inside the double quotes.

Comment: Was just about to add a follow up comment: When returning an empty string, you will always get a `PS>`, so it may be better like in your answer to return a space.

Comment: You could always use a [zero width space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) `function prompt { [char]8203 }`, or have a backspace after the space ```function prompt { " `b" }```. I think the backspace method is slightly better since it doesn't add anything when copying multiple console lines.

Comment: hmm, that didn't seem to make a difference for me.

Answer (score 2):

[Abraham Zinala's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65568583/45375) shows that it is the `prompt` function - described in the [about_Prompts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Prompts) conceptual help topic - that determines the string that PowerShell prints in interactive sessions when prompting the user for commands.

As [Calculuswhiz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4294399/calculuswhiz) notes, outputting the *empty* string (`''`) is *not* an option for not printing a prompt string at all, because PowerShell then defaults to `PS>`.

Printing a *single space* is one way to work around the problem, but that space does print. To prevent that, [Dabombber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11216160/dabombber) proposes workarounds in a comment on Abraham's question, but the **simplest solution as of Windows 10** is:

```
function prompt { "`0" }  # Fully HIDES the prompt string.
```

`` "`0" `` outputs a `NUL` (null character), which effectively hides the prompt string, without side effects, including in Windows Terminal and ConEmu.<sup>[1]</sup>

**On Windows 7**, the NUL prints *as a space*, in which case Dabombber's alternative helps:

```
# A space followed by a backspace char. in effect amounts to the empty string.
function prompt { " `b" }
```

Add this function to your `$PROFILE` file to hide the prompt string in all future sessions.

---

<sup>[1] Verified on version v20.11.24.0. Dabombber mentions that [ConEmu prints NUL characters as a *space*](https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu/issues/2158#issuecomment-706704608), but, given that ConEmu is `conhost.exe`-based, just like regular console windows, that applies only *up to Windows 7*.</sup>

Comment: All of the solutions appear to give my shell problems. If I type a single `'` after creating the `prompt` function, I get the exception `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException`. Perhaps it is something else influencing it.

Comment: @AdminOfThings, I don't see this problem - do you still see it if you start your session with `-noprofile`?

Comment: @mklement0 "Without side effects" would depend on your console, for example [ConEmu replaces `NUL` with a space](https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu/issues/2158#issuecomment-706704608).

Comment: @Dabombber, I don't know why, but that doesn't happen in practice, so the solution works fine in ConEmu as well - please see my update.

Comment: @mklement0 I mentioned it because it happens on Windows 7, or maybe with however it's configured. It'd also be a good idea to disable the PSReadLine error indicator, `Set-PSReadLineOption -PromptText ""`, otherwise it'll show up on the previous line (or crash for older PSReadLine versions).

Comment: Thanks, @Dabombber. `Set-PSReadLineOption -PromptText` is an interesting pointer, but as of PSReadline 2.1 (v1.2 that ships with Windows PowerShell doesn't even that option) it makes no difference - and it certainly _shouldn't_, given that it should only affect the portion of the prompt string that _matches_ the `-PromptText` argument, and there is no such portion here by definition (unless I'm missing something the 2.1 implementation is simply buggy).

Comment: @Dabombber: However, you're right that on _Windows 7_ - even in regular console windows (as I've just noticed, ConEmu too is `conhost`-based) - the NUL indeed prints as a space, so I've updated the answer to note that, along with showing your `" \`b"` solution as a workaround.

Comment: @mklement0 It looks like the check for a matching prompt string might only happen [on start-up or when `PromptText` is changed](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine/issues/971#issuecomment-513903412). So it's not really an issue, just something you might run into while playing around with the `prompt` function.

Comment: Thanks, @Dabombber - that clarifies the intent of `Set-PSReadLineOption -PromptText`: it tells PSReadLine what the prompt string's suffix - _including_ any trailing whitespace - is, if PSReadLine cannot determine that automatically or if the prompt function was changed in-session (the suffix is dynamically colored red to signal syntax errors). As of v2.1, there is an apparent bug where the specified suffix is _appended_ to the prompt string if it doesn't match the actual suffix, but, fortunately, that doesn't surface if there is _no_ prompt string.

Comment: @AdminOfThings, I think the GitHub link in Dabombber's most recent comment explains your symptom (shortening the prompt string in-session), and the underlying bug has since been fixed.